# Returning 100 Error Message in an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I need to write some code that can check if an iframes src property is going to return a 100 error. I've tried $ajax functions and i've tried using a youtube api but i just cant seem to get it to work. any ideas??